# C++ Octave in QtCreator (windows)

Tags: c++, qt-creator, octave

I am trying to use Octave with Qt creator on Windows but I don't no why i can't succeed to  link this library on this OS. I already tried on Ubuntu and everything works so i am a little bit lost...

I have octave3.6.4 (gcc 4.6.2) and i use the compiler gcc4.6.2 with Qt Creator.

my .pro file:

```css
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-01-26T11:35:00
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Octave/Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2/lib/octave/3.6.4/ -loctave -loctinterp -lcruft

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Octave/Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Octave/Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2/include

PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../Octave/Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2/lib/octave/3.6.4/libcruft.dll.a
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../Octave/Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2/lib/octave/3.6.4/liboctave.dll.a
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../Octave/Octave3.6.4_gcc4.6.2/lib/octave/3.6.4/liboctinterp.dll.a
```

my .h file:

```css
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <octave-3.6.4/octave/oct.h>
#include <octave-3.6.4/octave/octave.h>
#include <octave-3.6.4/octave/parse.h>
#include <octave-3.6.4/octave/toplev.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And i have many link errors such as C2144 syntax error ...

Comment: Octave has multiple packages for Windows, can you tell what's the one that you are using?

Comment: i use octave 3.6.4 with  mingw_gcc 3.6.2